# SharePoint 2019 On Prem- Modern Experience - How to set List view name above the list view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, list-view, modern-experience, 2019

Environment: SP 2019 On Premise

Requirement: We want to show list view Title above the gird. See below image:

[image]

This is a View created for the list. Though the data shown is as per the View, However the Title set for the View doesn't show up there.

Rather the List name is shown. How can we change this?

Comment: Is this list view added on different SharePoint modern page? or this is the same as default list URL?

Comment: It is the default list URL

Comment: I don't think you can change the list name specific to list view. You have to rename the list itself. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a web part of list on modern page, you can manually enter a name to list web part when you add it on modern page.

1. In Edit mode, after adding list web part, click on List name.

   [image]
2. Change the name as per your requirements like:

   [image]
3. Publish/Republish the page.

**Output**:

[image]

---

If you are within a SharePoint list & want to change the name, just double click on list name.

It will open a popup like below where you can rename the list & click Save:

[image]

**Note**:

1. It will rename the list & it is not specific to particular list view
2. The name of list web part will not change automatically when you change the list view from **Switch view options** dropdown.

**Documentation**: [Use the List web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-list-web-part-ef0a1b80-f8b3-443d-b04a-1e76c70b5537)

Comment: Hi Ganesh, Thanks for the response. I am not able to use the List View webpart bcoz "Conditional Column Formatting" is not available on it. Thus, i need to use the List View (generated on the List page itself). 
There are 2 reports / views which i have to show from the same list. Thus, can't use option of changing list name.

Comment: Then you cannot change the name shown above list view conditionally on selection of different list views. I has to be fixed. Conditional column formatting not working when you add list web part on modern page?

Comment: Hi @shoab, does this answers your question? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Comment: Sorry Ganesh for late reply. Yes, conditional formatting of column is not working in list view web part. If I can do conditional formatting then no need to go with list view shown in views drop-down (default page)

Comment: @shoab: Did you find a possibility to use column formatting inside the list view Webpart in SharePoint Server 2019, or is this still limited to the List View itself? I tried in SP Subscription Edition and there it worked!